# How to disable Old password displayed in browser during change password option in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

In my [ASP.Net MVC 3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3) Web application there is a change password option.

The browser is pushing some old password in the Old password text box.

This results in a validation message since the old password is wrong during post action.

I have read an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203364/remove-saved-old-password-from-browser-after-password-change) but its not serving the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Autocomplete need to set off from textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Another way is below...

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
```